# Click on multiple links with Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to web-scrape data from a structure that looks like that:

```
<div class = "tables">
        <div class = "table1">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "url1"
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "url1">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class = "table2">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "url3"
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "url4">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

The data that I want is in the div "data", and also on a some other pages accessible by clicking on the urls. I iterate through the 'tables' using BeautifulSoup, and I'm trying to click on the links with Selenium like so:

```
tables = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'tables')
 for line in tables:
     row = line.find_all('div', class_ = "row")
     for element in row:
         link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"href")]')
         #some code
```

In my script, this line

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href,"href")]')
```

always return the first url, when I want it to 'follow' BeautifulSoup and return to following hrefs. So is there a way to modify href depending on the url from the source code? I should add that all my urls are pretty similiar, except for the last part. (ex.: url1 = questions/ask/**1000** , url2 = questions/ask/**1001**)

I've also tried to find all the href in the page to iterate trough them using

```
links = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href]')
```

but that doesn't work either. Since the page contains a lot of links that aren't useful to me, I'm not sure if that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mix seems to be a bit complicated - Why not extracting the `href` with `BeautifulSoup` directly?

```
for a in soup.select('.tables a[href]'):
    link = a['href']
```

You also can modify it, concat with baseUrl and store in a list to iterate over:

```
urls = [baseUrl+a['href'] for a in soup.select('.tables a[href]')]
```

Or instead with selenium itself and with use of `find_elements` instead of `find_element` to get all links not only the first one:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="tables"]//a[@href]'):
    print(a.get_attribute('href'))
```

#### Example

```
baseUrl = 'http://www.example.com'

html='''
<div class = "tables">
        <div class = "table1">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "/url1"
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "/url1">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "table2">
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "/url3"
            </div>
            <div class = "row">
                <div class = 'data'>Useful Data</div>
                <a href = "/url4">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

urls = [baseUrl+a['href'] for a in soup.select('.tables a[href]')]

for url in urls:
    print(url)#or request the website,....
```

#### Output

```
http://www.example.com/url1
http://www.example.com/url1
http://www.example.com/url3
http://www.example.com/url4
```